# Не могу найти элемент xpath selenium facebook кнопка “Добавить в друзья”

Tags: html, python, selenium, facebook, xpath

Интересует верхняя кнопка "добавить в друзья"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time,random
import traceback;#uotput error
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

akki_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100000483633352'
#https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100000480483979

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()


driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/')#.maximize_window()#.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.manage().window().maximize();
#time.sleep(10)
element = driver.find_element_by_id("email") #находим поле с email

element.send_keys("****")#вводим значение

element = driver.find_element_by_id("pass") #находим поле с пароля

element.send_keys("****", Keys.ENTER)#вводим значение и нажимаем ентер 

#time.sleep(5)
driver.get(akki_url)

#time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys('', Keys.ESCAPE)


t=driver.page_source
#time.sleep(5)

#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="FriendRequestAdd"]/i')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="FriendRequestAdd"]')
#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(concat(" ", @class, " "), "FriendRequestAdd"]')
```

Ошибка что выдает консоль:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\1\fb\vremm_dla_prob.py",
>   line 37, in 
>       driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="FriendRequestAdd"]')
>   File
>   "C:\Users\Sylwia.thonny\BundledPython36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
>       return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)   File "C:\Users\Sylwia.thonny\BundledPython36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 978, in find_element
>       'value': value})['value']   File "C:\Users\Sylwia.thonny\BundledPython36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\Sylwia.thonny\BundledPython36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class="FriendRequestAdd"]"}
>   (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.43.600210
>   (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT
>   6.1.7601 SP1 x86)

Comment: приложите stacktrace ошибки в тело вопроса, пожалуйста

Comment: попробуйте `//button[contains(@class, "FriendRequestAdd")]` или `//button[contains(@class, "FriendRequestAdd")][0]`

Comment: Первый вариант без ошибки, но ничего не сделал, второй с ошибкой и тоже не получилось:                raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[contains(@class, "FriendRequestAdd")][0]"}
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86)

Comment: ну так вы вызываете find_element_by_xpath и ничего не делаете дальше. поэтому ничего не происходит. вызывайте какой-нибудь метод, например click

Comment: да, спасибо сработало, забыла)

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(@class, "FriendRequestAdd")]').click()
```